# Почему ошибка в sql запросе sqllite3

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def users_exist(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id = ?'", (user_id, )).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
```

Вот текст ошибки: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
Пытался пофиксить сам, но не получилось

Comment: Может запятую убрать? `(user_id, )` -> `(user_id)`

Comment: @SwaD (parameters are of unsupported type) - теперь такая ошибка

Comment: Попробуй вместо `'user_id = ?'` так `user_id = '?'` а если user_id число, то без кавычек

Comment: @SwaD "вопросы" в кавычки оборачивать не нужно, библиотека базы данных сама обернет строковые параметры в кавычки.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за уточнение. Скорректировал ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть так

```
def users_exist(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
```

Таблицы и поля выделять кавычками нельзя. В кавычки заключаются только строковые значения. Если строковое значение является строкой, оборачивать ? в запросе не надо, это сделает библиотека базы данных.

Текст запроса должен быть точно такой же, как если бы он выполняется в самой БД. Для проверки, сначала пишите запрос в БД, потом переносите его в код.